# How to access elements in nested formGroup with ngif?

Tags: angular

Suppose I have following setup:

```js
config = this.fb.group({
    group0: this.fb.group({
        group1: this.fb.group({
            enabled: [false]
        })
    }),
});
```

```html
<form class="form" [formGroup]="config">
    <p *ngIf="config.get('group0.group1.enabled').value">Working!!</p>
    <div formGroupName="group0">
        <p *ngIf="streamConfigForm.get('group0.group1.enabled').value">Working!!</p>
        <p *ngIf="group1.get('enabled').value">NOT Working!!</p>
        <div formGroupName="group1">
            <p *ngIf="enabled.value">NOT Working!!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Last `ngIf` are obviously not working. I know there is `formControlName` to access the controls for inputs. But is there a way to access nested the controls with `ngIf` without using the whole "path"? So basically I want to use the Not working example if possible. Angular knows which form I'm using and where I'm in the form by using `formGroupName`. Is there a way to access the controls without specifying the form and all formGroups?

So instead using:
`*ngIf="config.get('group0.group1.enabled').value"` I would prefer
something like this for first `formGroupName` div (group0)
`*ngIf="group0.get('group1.enabled').value"`
and
`*ngIf="enabled.value"`
for second `formGroupName` div (group1)

Comment: `config.get('group0.group1.enabled').value` ?

Comment: You could write a getter function in your component, that is called enabled and return the form group. You will still need to use the whole path, but the path is not included in the template anymore